# How to upload to a AWS S3 bucket with AES256 encryption(Server side encryption) using Active Storage Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

We are trying to upload files to an AES encrypted S3 bucket using Rails Active-Storage. We need to set up the Server-side encryption in the Rails.

But it throws an access denied error(Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied)).

The uploads were working successfully while using Paperclip. Now we are migrating from Paperclip to Active Storage. We were able to upload the file using the AWS SDK commands from the Rails console. But we need to set up the active storage. We followed the configuration as specified on the rails documentation. But there is no documentation for how to set the 's3_server_side_encryption' and 's3_permissions'.

We have done the basic configuration as specified on the rails documentation.
Reference: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the storage.yml:

```
upload: 
  server_side_encryption: 'AES256'
```

As long as your S3/KMS permissions are correctly set you should be good to go.

The bucket user will need the following KMS policy.

```
"kms:Decrypt",
"kms:Encrypt",
"kms:GenerateDataKey",
"kms:ReEncryptTo",
"kms:DescribeKey",
"kms:ReEncryptFrom"
```

Comment: I opened a PR to the Rails Guides as well. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38801

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not configuring the server's access point to the S3 bucket properly. See the following [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/index.html#Configuration).

Comment: @hair-amoor The uploads were working successfully while using Paperclip. Now we are migrating from Paperclip to Active Storage. 
We were able to upload the file using the AWS SDK commands from the Rails console. But we need to set up the active storage. We followed the configuration as specified on the rails documentation. But there are no documentation for how to set the 'server_side_encryption' and 's3_permissions'.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this I think. [Here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3)

Comment: Sorry No. We need the Rails Active-Storage S3 server_side_encryption configuration. The link you shared is for Paperclip.